# I'm trying to write a C code to sort String, but there always shows an error message in line 13

Tags: c

I'm trying to write a C code to sort strings, but there always shows an error message in line 13.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void SortString(char *strings[], int size)
{
    char temp[10];
    for(int i =0; i < size -1; i++)
        for(int j = i+1; j<size; j++)
        {
            if (strcmp(strings[i], strings[j])>0)
            {
                strcpy(temp, strings[i]);
                strcpy(strings[i], strings[j]); //Error: Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x100000fa6)
               strcpy(strings[j], temp);
           }
       }    }
   int main(){
   char *names[] = {"D", "C", "B", "A"};
   SortString(names, 4);    }
```

I know I can change `*name[]`into `name[][20]` and change `void SortString(char *strings[], int size)` to `void SortString(char strings[][20], int size)` to make the code correct, but why *name[] is wrong?

Comment: Because when you are using string constants and your array is pointing to them. You should allocate memory for names[] members and then copy the string.

Comment: We don't get to see your line numbers here, and we don't get to see the error message unless you tell us what it is. Instead of referencing a line number, add a comment to your code showing where you see the error, and add the actual error message to your question.

Comment: Why don't you just swap the pointers?

Answer (score 2):

I am referring to [this](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/storage-for-strings-in-c/) page.

```
char *names[] = {"D", "C", "B", "A"};
```

When you declare strings like this, they will be present in a read-only memory. You are trying to modify the content of the memory in your function and that is why you are getting the error.

Best way to achieve this functionality is to allocate memory for each member of the names array and then initialize it.

There are many ways to do it. I have given an example below.

```
char **names = malloc(MAX_ARRAY_SIZE * sizeof(char*));
if(NULL == names) {/**/}

names[0] = malloc(strlen("D")+1); //+1 for '\0' at the end.
if(NULL == names[0]) {/* Handle it*/}
strcpy(names[0], "D");
```

Comment: While technically correct, this is a lot of unnecessary memory allocation and string copying just to sort an array of pointers.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I agree to your point. I was just showing one of the way to achieve the functionality. And yes, I think your answer has a more optimized code!

Answer (score 1):

The data you're sorting is an array of `char *`, pointers to character strings. To reorder the array you just need to swap the pointers. You don't need to move the string contents. In fact you can't move the string contents in this case because they are **string literals**. You get a segfault when you try to write to read-only values.

I've slightly rewritten your function to just swap pointers and it seems to work now.

```
void SortString(char *strings[], int size)
{
    char *temp;
    for(int i = 0; i < size - 1; i++) {
        for(int j = i + 1; j < size; j++) {
            if (strcmp(strings[i], strings[j]) > 0) {
                temp = strings[i];
                strings[i] = strings[j];
                strings[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[Live demo on Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/kYCDSl)